# Catching keyboard input while fullscreen seems not to work

Tags: javascript, keyboard, fullscreen, three.js

I'm making a game with Three.js, and I need to get user input. I have two handler functions;

```
function press(evt) 
{
    console.log(evt);

    //evt = window.event;
    var code = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    switch(code) 
    {
        case KEY.W: input.up = true; break;
        case KEY.A: input.left = true; break;
        case KEY.S: input.down = true; break;
        case KEY.D: input.right = true; break;
        case KEY.E: input.e = true; break;
        case KEY.Z: input.z = true; break;
        case KEY.ONE: input.one = true; break;
        case KEY.CTRL: input.ctrl = true; break;
        case KEY.P: input.plus = true; break;
        case KEY.M: input.minus = true; break;
        case KEY.SH: input.shift = true; break;
    }
}

function release(evt)
{
    console.log(evt);

    //evt = window.event;
    var code = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    switch(code) 
    {
        case KEY.W: input.up = false; break;
        case KEY.A: input.left = false; break;
        case KEY.S: input.down = false; break;
        case KEY.D: input.right = false; break;        
        case KEY.E: input.e = false; break;
        case KEY.Z: input.z = false; break;
        case KEY.ONE: input.one = false; break;
        case KEY.CTRL: input.ctrl = false; break;
        case KEY.P: input.plus = false; break;
        case KEY.M: input.minus = false; break;
        case KEY.SH: input.shift = false; break;
    }
}
```

Both of which I use in other projects, and they work fine. This is how I attach the event listeners:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", press, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", release, false);
```

This works when the site normally loads, but does not work when the site goes fullscreen!

This is the while setup in the init(); function which gets called on body `onload` event:

```
        var init = function()
        {
            started = false;
            isFullscreen = false;

            changeFSState = function()
            {
                if (isFullscreen == true)
                {
                    isFullscreen = false;

                    game.stop(); //lol
                }
                else
                {
                    isFullscreen = true;
                }
            }

            container = document.getElementById("container");
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            document.addEventListener("keydown", press, false);
            document.addEventListener("keyup", release, false);

            document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeFSState, false);
            document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeFSState, false);

            game = new Game(container);
        }
```

Once a `play` button is clicked, this happens:

```
    THREEx.FullScreen.request(self.container);  
    self.renderer.setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
```

Now, as I said, catching input works until I click the `play` button (a link, actually), and then the console simply stops logging the events, as if they weren't happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[THREEx.FullScreen](http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.FullScreen.html) seems to be using this code:

```
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

And what you need is this:

```
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

Seems like [this is Chrome-only](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) though.

Comment: Huh, is there a Firefox alternative?